# Convert timestamps in a log file to epoch

Tags: shell

I'm accessing a log file where I have the timestamps at the beginning of each log. So I'm extracting the time and storing it in a variable to later convert it to epoch time.

So the problem that I'm facing is that whenever I execute it, It says `date: invalid date` and print the time stamps with a `\n` next to it. example, `10/23/19 15:45:01\n10/23/19 15:45:11`. Also this output comes up in between when I'm printing the normal timestamps (this issue stops everytime I comment the date function)

I've tried doing it something like this:

```sh
error_time=$(
    cat file | 
    grep -i 'word' -A 5 | 
    grep -o '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'
)
epoch_time=$(
    date -d '$error_time' +%s
) or $(
    date --date'$error_time' +%s(also +'%s')
)

for error_dir in $(ls -d $path)
do
    for error_logs in $(ls $error_dir)
    do
        error_time=$(
            cat $error_dir/$error_logs | 
            grep -i 'word' -A 5 | 
            grep -o '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'
        )
        epoch_time=$(
            date -d '$error_time' +%s
        ) or $(
            date --date'$error_time' +%s(also +'%s')
        )
    print $epoch_time
    done
done
```

the expected output should be in epoch time(seconds as far as I know) and what I'm getting is like this
`\n09/26/19 14:13:37\n09/26/19 14:34:31\n09/26/19 15:22:01`.

Comment: What does the contents of your `file` look like?  Can you reformat your question to show the blocks of code you are invoking, by indenting your script with 4 leading space characters/

Comment: Don't use `ls` for iterating over filenames.

Comment: i think `'$error_time'` might evaluate to just `'$error_time'` unlike `"$error_time"` which would evaluate to the contents of `$error_time` variable.

Comment: always double-quote the uses of parameter expansion unless you want them to end up causing argument separation

Comment: What is this `or` command you're calling? What shell is this? bash does not have a builtin `print` command but ksh does.

Comment: Following up on "don't use `ls`" -- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: @glennjackman you might be right, i don't know of any `or` command in bash — so maybe it's some zsh or something. Idk if bash would treat it as a syntax error or incorporate it as a string…

Comment: Bash will treat it like `var=value cmd arg ...` which sets the variable only for the duration of the command. But now I see that the OP is writing a kind of pseudocode

Answer (score 1):

`perl` is really well suited to this type of problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# Replace occurrences of 'mm/dd/yy HH:MM:SS' with epoch time

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

while(<>) {
        s@(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d\d \d{1,2}:\d\d:\d\d)@
                sprintf scalar Time::Piece->strptime(
                $1, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")->epoch@ge;
        print;
}
```

This gives results like:

```
$ printf '1/3/19 4:23:04 text \ntext: 12/14/19 12:35:23\n' | ./a.pl
1546489384 text 
text: 1576326923
```

Answer (score 0):

You script after fixing could look like this:

```
# don't parse ls
for f in "$path"/*/*; do
    #    ^     ^ quote your variables
    error_time=$(
        # don't try to win useless cat award
        grep -i 'word' -A 5 "$f" | 
        #                   ^  ^ quote your variables
        grep -o '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'
    )
    epoch_time=$(date -d"$error_time" +%s)
    #                   ^           ^ note
    printf "%d\n" "$epoch_time"
    #             ^           ^ quote your variables
    #    ^ there is no "print" command     
done
```

It could be wise to get to know:

- [about shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) that automagically inspects your scripts and highlights problems with it.
- [how to debug bash scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155570/209955)
- [what the difference between single and double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)
- [why you shouldn't parse ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [similar thread on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)
- and that `cat` is used to concatenate multiple files, so don't [use it on a single file](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Do a redirection `grep ... < "$file"` or pass the file as the argument to the utility `grep ... "$file"`.